# File read presents none of files actual data

Tags: java, android

Hi I am trying to print a text file with the double data, line by line, read from a file on my android device however it doesn't seem to be working what is wrong? I get no errors but not proper print out?

in my bodyTempInfo View I get readout:

```
Your Body Temperature Readings are:[]
```

my temp2.txt file, there is a total of 1440 numbers, not going to paste them all here

```
37.06750839
36.89390613
36.88484785
36.81941363
36.81815453
36.97372599
37.0510889
36.90421803
36.90452867
36.81245808
36.91739551
37.05989195
36.80757783
36.85141347
37.04927826
36.80384926
36.94000689
37.04948705
37.07007973
36.95211596
37.05161886
36.97029703
37.03218835
36.89381629
```

My bodyTempInfo.Java

```
package com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class bodyTempInfo extends AppCompatActivity {


    ArrayList<Double> currentBodyTemp;

    public void displayCurrentBodyTempArray(View view) throws FileNotFoundException {

        ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file


//Read text from file

        File file = new File(sdcard, "temp2.txt");

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                list.add(Double.parseDouble(line));
                text.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {

        }


/*
        Scanner file2 = new Scanner(new File(sdcard, "temp.txt"));

        while (file2.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = file2.nextLine();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
            scanner.useDelimiter(",");
            while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                list.add(scanner.nextDouble());
            }
            scanner.close();
        }
        */
        currentBodyTemp = list;
        displayBodyTemp("Your Body Temperature Readings are:" + list);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_body_temp_info);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        try {
            displayCurrentBodyTempArray(findViewById(R.id.bodyTempInfoArray));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    private void displayBodyTemp(String bodyTemp) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bodyTempInfoArray);
        textView.setText(bodyTemp);
    }


}
```

logcat

```
10-25 14:15:11.041 11084-11084/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
10-25 14:15:11.041 11084-11084/? E/Zygote: v2
10-25 14:15:11.041 11084-11084/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10385
10-25 14:15:11.041 11084-11084/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
10-25 14:15:11.051 11084-11084/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G920V_5.1.1_0033
10-25 14:15:11.051 11084-11084/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
10-25 14:15:11.051 11084-11084/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-25 14:15:11.111 11084-11084/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
10-25 14:15:11.111 11084-11084/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
10-25 14:15:11.211 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
10-25 14:15:11.231 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
10-25 14:15:11.241 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
10-25 14:15:11.241 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4
10-25 14:15:11.241 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 I/InjectionManager: Constructor com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4, Feature store :{}
10-25 14:15:11.241 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
10-25 14:15:11.301 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
10-25 14:15:11.491 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
10-25 14:15:11.491 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
10-25 14:15:11.761 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
10-25 14:15:11.771 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4.MainActivity isFragment :false
10-25 14:15:11.791 11084-11175/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-25 14:15:11.821 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
10-25 14:15:11.821 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
10-25 14:15:11.891 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
10-25 14:15:11.951 11084-11175/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
10-25 14:15:11.991 11084-11175/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-25 14:15:12.001 11084-11175/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 I/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0x7f79c8abc0 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = 1912140464 
10-25 14:15:12.011 11084-11175/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/OpenGLRenderer: Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 8192
10-25 14:15:12.011 11084-11175/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
10-25 14:15:12.011 11084-11175/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
10-25 14:15:12.391 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4.MainActivity
10-25 14:15:12.391 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4.MainActivity
10-25 14:15:12.461 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2f8d81aa time:4028871
10-25 14:15:12.801 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{81a0e76 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2f8d81aa {com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4.MainActivity}} show : true
10-25 14:15:14.701 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2f8d81aa time:4031112
10-25 14:15:14.921 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
10-25 14:15:14.971 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 time:4031384
10-25 14:15:15.051 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
10-25 14:15:15.051 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
10-25 14:15:15.071 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
10-25 14:15:15.121 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4.bodyTempInfo isFragment :false
10-25 14:15:15.121 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
10-25 14:15:15.141 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
10-25 14:15:15.141 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
10-25 14:15:15.181 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
10-25 14:15:15.181 11084-11175/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
10-25 14:15:15.201 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4.bodyTempInfo
10-25 14:15:15.201 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4.bodyTempInfo
10-25 14:15:15.271 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1f826b14 time:4031688
10-25 14:15:15.311 11084-11084/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{81a0e76 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2f8d81aa {com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4.MainActivity}} show : false
```

My content_body_temp_info.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_body_temp_info"
    tools:context="com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4.bodyTempInfo">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text = "Body Temperature Measurements will go here"
        android:id = "@+id/bodyTempInfoArray"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

my MainActivity.java

```
package com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    UUID myUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
    private static final int DISCOVER_DURATION = 300;
    private static final int REQUEST_BLU = 1;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<Double> currentBodyTemp;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

        //If there are paired devices
        /*Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            //Loop through the paired devices
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                //add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        }
        */

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy

        Intent discoverableIntent = new
                Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);




    }

    ArrayList<Double> lightInfo;

    public void sendLightFile() {

        String filename = "lightInfo";
        String string = "Here is light info" + lightInfo;
        FileOutputStream outputStream;

        try {
            outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Send information over bluetooth?

    }



    public void goToBodyInfo(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, bodyTempInfo.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void sendLight(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectTest.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }


    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        }
    };


    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();


        public AcceptThread() {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket,
            // because mmServerSocket is final
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
                tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("CircadianRhythmMonitor", myUUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;
            // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
            while (true) {
                try {
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                    //manageConnectedSocket(socket);
                    //mmServerSocket.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish
         */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                   // mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            //.sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }


    private void displayBodyTemp(String bodyTemp) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bodyTempInfoArray);
        textView.setText(bodyTemp);
    }



}
```

my AndroidManfiest.xml

```
package="com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4" >

    <!-- Allows bluetooth to be used from this app -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".bodyTempInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_body_temp_info"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ConnectTest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_body_temp_info"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Why are you posting that logcat? What's in it about your problem? Why are you posting an xml file? Please reduce your code to the relevant part of reading that file line by line. Don't just dump code.

Comment: Apologies @greenapps I thought it might be relevant as body tempinfo file is referenced in the log cathe as reading null which I think my issuemail is

Answer (score 0):

In your `displayBodyTemp()` function, you are passing a String and using `+` to add an arraylist. That is the story.You need to pass a string only. Or override the `toString()` method of the `Arraylist`

OR, try this:

```
displayBodyTemp("Your Body Temperature Readings are:" + text);
```